# Angle between 3 vectors

Tags: matrices

Meta elements are tags used in HTML and XHTML documents to provide structured metadata about a Web page. They are part of a web page's head section. Multiple Meta elements with different attributes can be used on the sam

Comment: $|BA|$ and $|BC|$ should be the same.

Comment: Was that latest edit intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have done something wrong in your calculations

$\vec{BA} = (-0.5,-0.5,-0.5)$

$|\vec{BA}| = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\vec{BC} = (0.5,0.5,-0.5)$

$|\vec{BC}| = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\vec{BA}\cdot\vec{BC} = -0.5(0.5) + (-0.5)(0.5) + (-0.5)(-0.5) = -0.25$

So the angle is $\arccos(\frac{-0.25}{(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2})=\arccos(\frac{-1}{3})=109.5^\circ$

Answer (score 1):

Three points determine a triangle which has three angles.  The angles of a triangle add up to $180^\circ$, so if one of them is more than $45^\circ$, the others must each be less than $135^\circ.$  I did not actually check your results, but perhaps you should calculate all three angles, and see if your answer is self-consistent and also consistent with the problem given.

Here is a picture of the situation:

[image]

As others have pointed out, the cosine of the angle between two vectors is the dot product of the vectors, divided by the product of the length of each of the vectors.

Comment: I double checked my calculations and had an error in $C-B$, the vector is actually $(1/2, 1/2, -1/2)$. The angle is smaller than 135$^\circ$, it is about 125$^\circ$ but that also seems incorrect.

Comment: Looks to be that the dot product of $A-B$ and $C-B$ is $1/4.$

Comment: That seems more accurate, I got $-1/4$ but, the formula I used asks to divide by $|BA| |BC|$. Is that what you did?

Comment: Yes, you are right, we should divide by the lengths of the vectors.